# In SWI-Prolog, how to transform, convert, mutate, evolute, change a set list [ 1, ( 2, 3 ) ] to [ 1, 2, 3 ]?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have a program that performs a user input with read/1 clause. Then creates a list containing the input Information as follow:

```
write('Input' )
read(Folks),

consult('database.pl.pl'), 
Predic =.. [Inform, [ Name, Bussi, Folks ] ],
assert(Predic),
```

In the disk is writen:

```
Inform(['Juc', 'Rockstar', 'Desprogra', 1899, 1999, ( 'Bill', 'Steven', 'Demi' ) ]).
```

So, I can't have the () at the end of the list:

```
..., ( 'Bill', 'Steven', 'Demi' ) ]
```

I know that is is caused because, the: `read(Folks),` That have to read `'Bill', 'Steven', 'Demi'`.

Comment: If you know exactly the format, what prevents from you just to use pattern matching?

Comment: Hi Eugene and thank you, that just doesn't passed to my mind ^_^ I think it is because I never learned this in swi-prolog, but may it should be time to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog doesn't have tuples, since we can implement them as a recursive application of comma operator. For general processing, read the section about [analysing terms](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=manipterm). In particular, ([=..](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D..%29/2))/2 it's often used to perform arguments processing of a structure, but what you need here could be

```
conj_list((A,B), [A|Bs]) :- conj_list(B, Bs), !.
conj_list(T, [T]).
```

(the cut position is important, please experiment to see what it does). Now, the simpler code to get the job done should be

```
?- maplist(conj_list, [1,(2,3)],L), flatten(L, F).
L = [[1], [2, 3]],
F = [1, 2, 3].
```

Comment: Hi CapelliC, it was perfect! Now i learned about maplist and regex ~_~

Answer (score 1):

Let:

```
superflatten([],A,A).

superflatten([[]|Q],A,R) :- !,
   superflatten(Q,A,R).

superflatten([H|Q],A,R) :-
  H =.. [K|L],
  ( L = [] -> append(A,[K],T1); superflatten(L,A,T1) ),
  superflatten(Q,T1,R).

superflatten(X,R) :- superflatten(X,[],R).
```

some examples of queries and answers:

```
debug]  ?- superflatten([],R).
R = [].

[debug]  ?- superflatten([a,b],R).
R = [a, b].

[debug]  ?- superflatten([a,[b,c]],R).
R = [a, b, c].

[debug]  ?- superflatten([a,[],[b,c]],R).
R = [a, b, c].

[debug]  ?- superflatten([a,(b,c)],R).
R = [a, b, c].

[debug]  ?- superflatten([a,t(b,c)],R).
R = [a, b, c].
```

Comment: Thanks pasaba por aqui.